# Load information into CloudPage form

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I have a cloudpage in sfmc with a form to update some customers' information. The function is to pass the subscriberkey parameter in the URL and search Salesforce for this ID. Check if this ID exists in the Contact or Lead object, if so, update it. If not, create a new Lead.
When the user opens the page, the form preloads the information. All functions are working perfectly.

But what I need now is for the form to not load the information. I just want the information to be loaded into my form, after entering the CPF (Brazilian personal id) and searching for the information in SF.
My form has the following information: CPF, First Name, Last Name, Email.

Does anyone have any tips on how to proceed?[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use a combination of front-end javascript, which will "listen" to CPF form field being updated. And a JSON code resource in SFMC, which will receive the CPF number as a parameter, and return JSON with all the field values. The same JavaScript function responsible for listening to the CPF field, can also parse the returned JSON, and use this data to populate the fields in the front-end

Answer (score 0):

My simple solution would be -
create cloudpage1 and create the form element here and set redirect to cloudpage2 for checking if details are valid. If not valid (ie lookupcount = 0) then return "record not found"